# I added tailwindcss 3 to the vue-sfc-rollup project but it doesn't work

Tags: vuejs3, tailwind-css

I added tailwindcss 3 to the vue-sfc-rollup project but it doesn't work

```
ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error   
error  in ./dev/index.css

Syntax Error: Error: PostCSS plugin tailwindcss requires PostCSS 8.
Migration guide for end-users:
https://github.com/postcss/postcss/wiki/PostCSS-8-for-end-users
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
npm install -D tailwindcss@npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat postcss@^7 autoprefixer@^9
```

> Once the rest of your tools have added support for PostCSS 8, you can
> move off of the compatibility build by re-installing Tailwind and its
> peer-dependencies using the latest tag:

```
npm uninstall tailwindcss
npm install -D tailwindcss@latest postcss@latest autoprefixer@latest
```

For more information see [here](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/installation#post-css-7-compatibility-build)